# PostgreSQL: relation does not exist error

Tags: postgresql, go

Perhaps this error can be caused by problems with the SCHEMA, I tried to fix it, but I was completely confused.

Here is the detailed description.

There is a separate file that runs the following commands:

```
CREATE DATABASE weather;
CREATE SCHEMA public;
CREATE SCHEMA schema1;

SET search_path = schema1, public;

CREATE TABLE "Sities" (
                    Id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
                    name TEXT,
                    country TEXT,
                    weather_id_api int);

CREATE TABLE "Forecasts" (
                    Id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
                    city_id int,
                    time DATE,
                    temp INT,
                    humidity INT,
                    pressure INT);

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO postgres;
GRANT usage ON SCHEMA public TO postgres;
```

The execution of each command is checked for errors. These commands are executed without problems.

Further in another file such commands are executed:

```
SET search_path = schema1, public;
INSERT INTO "Sities" (name, country, weather_id_api)
            SELECT 'Orenburg', "RU", 234234
            WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT name FROM "Sities" WHERE name="Orenburg");
```

**The last command causes an error:**

> panic: pq: Relation "Sities" does not exist
>
> goroutine 1 [running]: main.PostToDatabase(0x11731ee0)
>           D:/Go/src/WeatherSoket/main.go:135 +0x40f main.Update()
>           D:/Go/src/WeatherSoket/main.go:150 +0x52 main.main()
>           D:/Go/src/WeatherSoket/main.go:165 +0xbe exit status 2

Comment: Why don't you reference the schema name by name? `schema.table`

Comment: Can you run this queries in console?

Comment: Why you added extra `""` to the table name?

Comment: @salient, can you tell it in more detail?

Comment: `CREATE TABLE schema.tablename …`, `INSERT INTO schema.tablename`

Comment: @Eugene Lisitsky, I tried to execute just INSERT INTO ... VALUES (...) and got the same problem.

Comment: @Being Sunny, "extra"? I think, without quotes the PostgreSQL will result in lowercase.

Comment: @salient, I tried. Maybe, not correctly, but I got the same error.

Comment: after you create the tables, can you assert that they are in the schema you expect them to be?

Comment: @salient, actually I do not know. I execute the command **SET search_path = schema1, public** for this. It is not right? Can you explain how this works? Nevertheless when I use **INSERT INTO schema1."Sities"** or **INSERT INTO schema1.Sities** or **INSERT INTO "schema1"."Sities"** the problem remains the same.

Comment: What's the output of this? `select table_catalog, table_schema, table_name
from information_schema.tables
where table_name = 'Sities';` Strings like 'Orenburg' take single quotes in standard SQL. Database objects like "Sities" take double quotes. I don't know what `"RU"` is.

Comment: @Mike Sherrill 'Cat Recall', https://ibb.co/iCLaRG

Comment: Show the code that executes the two separate sets of SQL commands, and also show the code that connects to the database. Also at the top of your first file you create a database called `weather`, your subsequent commands are executed outside of that new database since the script runs in the database to which you originally connected. Anyways your not giving us the whole picture so we are unable to help.

Comment: And also from your link (https://ibb.co/iCLaRG) it's clear that you are either connecting to the wrong database (the image says postgres and who knows what database your Go code is connecting to...) or that your first set of commands, the ones that create the tables, did not work as you inteded, and so you have no tables to work with.

Comment: @mkopriva, you right, I forgot to connect to the created databasе after it was created.

Comment: @mkopriva, if you if you can, post this comment in answer field.

Comment: After this: 
`_, err = predb.Exec("CREATE DATABASE weather;")`
`_, err = predb.Exec("CREATE SCHEMA schema1;")`
I had to add this:
`predb.Close()`

And only then connect to the created database and create tables.

Answer (score 1):

This works - try to check quotes `"` and apostrophes `'`:

```
SET search_path = schema1, public;

INSERT INTO "Sities" (name, country, weather_id_api)
            SELECT 'Orenburg', 'RU', 234234
            WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT name FROM "Sities" WHERE name='Orenburg');
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/5abd9/4

Comment: `SHOW search_path;` ?

Comment: "$user", public

Comment: So `search_path` was not applied. Do you use any connection pooler?